# is there a Workaround for fixing a Safari bug, that builts artefacts by using border-bottom with complex border-radius

Tags: css, safari, border, radius

I try to create a handwritten looked underline to input.

With this complex border-radius, Chrome looks great. In Safari, however, these artifacts appear.

I tried to fix it with

```
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
```

from: https://tumble.sneak.co.nz/post/928998513/fixing-the-background-bleed

```
input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 130px 50px/4px 2px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/matzR/pen/dybpXgO

Safari: artefacts over the input
[image: Safari: artefacts over the input]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari seems to have some *interesting* decisions as far as figuring out the border color goes. Try zooming at this, for instance:

```
input {
  border: 0.001px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 130px 50px/4px 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

[image: very cursed]

I guess the linked workaround doesn't work because the border isn't *inside* the element?

But this is OK ([codepen](https://codepen.io/YellowAfterlife/pen/JjPRbZw)):

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 130px 50px/4px 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

[image: not so cursed]

My other considerations were using a SVG element for background and/or using `border-image-slice` to simulate the behaviour.